# Codeigniter, open and edit view file on webpage

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a basic CMS in codeigniter, and would like to be able to open view files inside the backend of the CMS, i.e on a webpage. The advantage of this is being able to upload views directly from a code editor/ftp client, but be able to modify them using the CMS if this option isn't availble. I know i could do it using a database, but being able to FTP views directly is required.

I've tried Googling various things, but the keywords seem to pull up completely different results.

So it's basically opening the file, putting it's contents in a form/textarea box, then on saving it saves directly to the file again, but i can't find any examples!

Thanks in advance!

C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List Files**

Using [directory iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) you can make a list of all files of a folder. (in your case the list of all .php files into the views folder)

---

**Get / Set the content of the file**

Then using [file_get_contents you](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can retrieve the content of the file.

and using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) you can set the content of the file.

You can also check

- [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

which does the same of file_get_contents and file_put_contents...

---

**As for the validation**

You may check before getting the file content if the file [is_readable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

You may also want to check before setting the content if the file [is_writable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

---

**Complements**

Also, if I were you, I would add a syntax highlighter for your cms, you may want to check the one that is used by some big fish like :  Apache, Aptana, Mozilla, Yahoo, Wordpress, ...

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: Thanks Hipny, really appreciate your help and great idea on using the SyntaxHighlighter! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a (what I believe to be) working solution from a long time ago
I can say that it worked in the past but I make no guarantee that it is still compatible with your current systems.

Features

- Password login (not very secure but will keep away casual users)
- Prevents you from hitting the back button and overwriting your changes with old code (could probably update $rand to use timestamp instead of a random)

There are probably a lot of updates you could do to this.

This was mainly a quick and dirty solution just to get something working

If you need it to list files also, you could try outputting the results of readdir or scandir (for something quick) into a div. Alternatively, @Hipny has the right idea as to how to build your own

Code:

```
<?
$rand = mt_rand(0, 65535);
setcookie("check", $rand);
if ($_POST['pass'] != ""){
setCookie ("auth", hash("sha512", $_POST['pass']));
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;" . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] . "'>";
}
if ($_GET['logout'] == "1"){
setCookie("auth","");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;" . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] . "'>";
}
if ($_COOKIE['auth'] != "!!!! INSERT YOUR OWN SHA512 HASH HERE !!!!"){
echo "<center><h1>Authentication required</h1><br /><form action='" . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]. "?" . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] . "' method='post'><input type='password' name='pass'><input type='submit' value='Authenticate'></form></center>";
die();
}
$rand = mt_rand(0, 65535);
setcookie("check", $rand);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function reloadFile(){
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            var redir = "?";
            for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++){
                if (vars[i].indexOf("file=") == -1 && vars[i].indexOf("save=1") == -1){
                    if (redir == "") redir = "?" + vars[i];
                    else redir += "&" + vars[i];
                }
            }
            while (redir.indexOf("&&") != -1) redir = redir.replace("&&", "&");
            document.location.href = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.indexOf("?")) + redir + "&file=" + document.getElementById("newfile").value;
        }
        </script>
<title>Editing file: <? echo $_GET['file']; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan=2">
<input id="newfile" type="text" size="135" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('load').click()"><input id="load" type="button" value="Load" onClick="if (confirm('Discard changes?')) reloadFile();">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<?php
function ex($message){
throw new Exception($message);
}
function read($file){
try{
@$handle = fopen($file, "rb") or ex("Read Error!");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
return htmlspecialchars($contents);
} catch (Exception $e) {
return "Creating new file.";
}
}
function save(){
$data = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data']);
if($_GET['file'] != "") {
      $fp=fopen($_GET['file'], "w");
      fwrite($fp, $_POST['data']);
      fclose($fp);
}
}
//echo strlen ($_POST['data']);
if ($_POST['data'] != "" && $_COOKIE['check'] == $_POST['checksum']) save();
else if ($_GET['save'] == 1) echo "<div id='abort'><h1><font color='FF0000'>Save checksum did not match: save aborted!</font> <a href=\"javascript:void(document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none')\" style='color: #000000;text-decoration:none;'>X</a></h1></div>";
?>
        <form name="dataform" id="dataform" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],"&save=1") === false) echo "&save=1"; ?>" onSubmit="return confirm('Do you want to save?');">
        <textarea name="data" wrap="off" id="data"<? if ($_POST['h'] != "") echo " rows='" . $_POST['h'] . "'"; else if ($_GET['h'] != "") echo " rows='" . $_GET['h'] . "'"; 
<?
    if ($_GET['file'] != "") echo read($_GET['file']);
?></textarea><br />
<input type="hidden" value="<? echo $rand ?>" id="checksum" name="checksum">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

</script>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" Value="Save">
<input type="button" Value="Revert" onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to revert?')) document.location.href = document.location.href;">
<input type="button" Value="Logout" onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')) document.location.href = '<? echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] ?>?logout=1';">
</td>
<td align="right">
<input name="h" id="h" onKeyUp='document.getElementById("data").rows = this.value'> x <input name="w" id="w" onKeyUp='document.getElementById("data").cols = this.value'>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("data").style.width = document.body.clientWidth * .9;
document.getElementById("data").style.height = document.body.clientHeight * .8;
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the starting code, will give it a go and hopefully get it figured out :)